# Split two tables with a blank row in excel

Tags: excel

I need to separate tables with a blank row that continuously drops down when a new entry is made at the bottom of a table. I need the tables to remain separate but they need to stay on the same sheet, is there any way to do this in excel or will i have to mess with VB?

Didn't initially want to use a macro in every sheet for it because the file is already starting to slow up but i don't mind trying if i need to.

I assumed excel would do it automatically but this was not the case, tried merging and unmerging cells below the bottom entries hoping excel would recognise that and drop it down but this did not work either.

Comment: Why must the tables be on the same sheet? What about putting the tables next to each other instead of one above the other?

Comment: The tables being above one another is purely visual, management seems to not want to wait the 5 seconds for a scrollbar, its either this or break up the worksheet i even further into sections in separate files but they requested a way around this

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this

```
    Public Sub InsertRowsInTable(ByVal targetTableName As String)
   
    ' Ask user how many rows to ask
    Dim rowsToAdd As Variant
    rowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1)
   
    ' If user didn't input anything, default to 1
    If rowsToAdd = vbNullString Then rowsToAdd = 1
   
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range(targetTableName).ListObject
   
    Dim rowinsert As Integer
   
    ' Resize the table to add rows
    For rowinsert = 0 To rowsToAdd - 1
        targetTable.Range.EntireRow(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + 1).Insert
    Next
    targetTable.Resize targetTable.Range.Resize(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + rowsToAdd)
End Sub
```